# VBA Compile Error "Named argument not found"

Tags: excel, vba

Running Excel 2007 I get `Compile Error: Named argument not found` running the following:

```
Private Sub wykonaj_button_Click()
Worksheets("Arkusz1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123"
SolverReset
SolverOk SetCell:="$B$18", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$B$11:$D$13", _
    Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$B$11:$D$11", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="1"
SolverOk SetCell:="$B$18", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$B$11:$D$13", _
    Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$B$12:$D$12", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="1"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$B$13:$D$13", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="1"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$B$14", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$C$14", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$D$14", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$E$11", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$E$12", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely need to include the reference to the Solver add-in.

[MSDN SolverOK Function for Office 2007](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb257045(v=office.12).aspx)

> Before you use this function, you must establish a reference to the
> Solver add-in. In the Visual Basic Editor, with a module active, click
> **References** on the **Tools** menu, and then select the **Solver.xlam** check
> box under **Available References**. If **Solver.xlam** does not appear under
> **Available References**, click **Browse** and open Solver.xlam in the
> \office12\library\Solver subfolder.

[MSDN Solver VBA Fuction Office 2013 and later](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196600.aspx)

> Before you can use the Solver VBA functions from VBA, you must enable
> the Solver add-in in the Excel Options dialog box.
>
> 1. Click the **File** tab, and then click **Options** below the **Excel** tab.
> 2. In the **Excel Options** dialog box, click **Add-Ins**.
> 3. In the **Manage** drop-down box, select **Excel Add-ins**, and then click **Go**.
> 4. In the **Add-Ins** dialog box, select **Solver Add-in**, and then click OK.
>
> After you have enabled the Solver add-in,
> Excel will auto-install the Add-in if it is not already installed, and
> the **Solver** command will be added to the **Analysis** group on the **Data** tab in the ribbon.
>
> Before you can use the Solver VBA functions in the
> Visual Basic Editor, you must establish a reference to the Solver
> add-in. In the Visual Basic Editor, with a module active, click
> **References** on the **Tools** menu, and then select **Solver** under Available References. If Solver does not appear under **Available References**,
> click **Browse**, and then open Solver.xlam in the \Program
> Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\Library\SOLVER subfolder.